# Bold calendar dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am using the Telerik radDateTimePicker control in a webapp and would like to make it a bit more functional.  Similar to the functionality of the Outlook calendar, where dates appear bolded if there is an underlying appointment, I would like to bold the dates that have underlying data.

Has anyone done anything like this before?  Tips/suggestions/sample code are all welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestion... I was actually able to get this working in the meantime.

```
private void FormatCalendar()
{
    DataTable dtCalendar = this.Utils.GetDatesForCalendar(Session["LoginId"].ToString());
    if (dtCalendar.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtCalendar.Rows)
        {
            if (!(System.Convert.IsDBNull(dr["LogDate"])))
            {
                RadCalendarDay NewDay = new RadCalendarDay();

                NewDay.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["LogDate"]);

                txtDate.Calendar.SpecialDays.Add(NewDay);
                txtDate.Calendar.SpecialDays[NewDay].ItemStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Robert